# Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analsysis Section 3.2 Problem 14: Critic my Proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on E and $m(E)<\infty$. For each $\epsilon>0$, show that there is a measurable set $F$ contained $E$ such that $f$ is bounded in $F$ and $m(E\sim F)<\epsilon$.

**My Attempt at Proof**: By hypothesis that $f$ is finite a.e. on $E$, there is a $B \subseteq E$ such that $m(B)=0$, and $f$ is finite on $E\sim B$. Since $$x\in B \iff \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, |f(x)|>n,$$ then $B=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x\in E: |f(x)|>n\}$. Then for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, consider the set $B_n:=\{x\in E: |f(x)|>n\}$; each $B_n$ is measurable since $f$ is measurable on $E$. Also, the collection $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a descending collection of measurable sets, and $m(B_1)\leq m(E)<\infty$. Hence by continuity of measure: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}m(B_n)=m \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n \right)=m(B)=0.$$

Therefore, given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$m(B_N)<\epsilon.$$
Then, define $F \subseteq E$ by $F:=E\sim B_N =\{x\in E: |f(x)|\leq N \}$. Then, $f$ is indeed bounded in $F$ (by $N$) and by excision property, since $m(B_N)<\infty$, then $$m(E\sim F)=m(E\sim (E\sim B_N))=m(B_N)<\epsilon.$$ As required. Is my proof correct?

Comment: One small correction: "$f$ is finite on $E\sim B$" means (to me) that $E\sim B\subset\{x\in E: |f(x)|<\infty\}$. This is the same as $\cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n\subset B$, and this is sufficient for your the rest of your argument.

Comment: I see, but then we can remedy this problem by: $0\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} m(B_n)  \leq m(B) = 0$ right?

Comment: Wait, if anyone is still reading this, am I right in "defining" $f(x)=^+_- \infty \iff \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, |f(x)|>n$?

Comment: Yes to your remedy.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be answering my own comment. I see that you correction is really airtight. I think, a better way to 'define' $f(x) = ^+_- \infty$ is $f(x) = ^+_- \infty \iff \forall \varepsilon>0, |f(x)|>\varepsilon$. In that case, my earlier 'definition' does not hold both ways but only for the 'if' direction.